# code::blocks default hello world in C terminated with status 1993077897 or -1073741510

Tags: c, codeblocks

After downloading and installing `Code::Blocks` with `MinGW`, I just started a new console project on it and it created a `main.c` file with this content:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And it does compile. However, when I run it, no "Hello world!" is shown in the console and there is a message like

```
Process terminated with status 1993077897 (0 minutes, 3 seconds)
```

or

```
Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minutes, 7 seconds)
```

in the build log.

I can truly say that I just don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Are you closing the console by clicking `X` rather than pressing enter? Otherwise the code looks fine.

Comment: I did both. 1993077897 is the number I get when I press a key and -1073741510 is the one I get when I press the X.

Comment: Are you sure codeblocks compiles this source file and runs the appropriate executable from the right project?

Comment: You can check [FAQ](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ-Compiling_%28errors%29) for common issues, see if something helps you.

Comment: @KartikAnand I checked it. If there was something relevant, I missed it.

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk it is a default project. I changed nothing concerning paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved: Kapersky was doing its job too well and blocked the process before it could even display a simple "Hello world". It warned me a long time after that, asking me repeatedly to delete the executable.

Comment: Program is clearly unsafe since it's written in C instead of <insert recent fad language>

Answer (score 0):

try:
    int main(void)
    {
        printf("Hello World");
        return 0;
    }

I may be wrong, but i think the problem is in the main() i think you need to change that to main(void)

Comment: If that doesnt work i think it has to do with your project and how you build/compile it. Your code is fine though

Comment: Sorry, adding void didn't change anything.

Comment: then the code isnt the problem. its the project. make sure you have built it right.

Comment: The project is a default one. It is supposed to be running fine without modifications.
For the building/compilation, I Just press the build&run button. Is there something wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this
Go to `Settings->Compiler->Reset Defaults` Hope it works!